# C# Aligning 2 Strings via a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

In my listbox, I would like to display the following

```
String 1(left aligned - default)                 int value(right aligned)
```

Is there a way to do this, or can there only be 1 alignment in a listbox?

Answer (score 2):

If you are Using in Winforms, you can use this code.

You can set the `DrawMode` property of the ListBox to `DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed`

```
ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
listBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
listBox.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(listBox_DrawItem);

void listBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox list = (ListBox)sender;
    if (e.Index > -1)
    {
        object item = list.Items[e.Index];
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
        SizeF size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(item.ToString(), e.Font);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(item.ToString(), e.Font, brush, e.Bounds.Left + (e.Bounds.Width / 2 - size.Width / 2), e.Bounds.Top + (e.Bounds.Height / 2 - size.Height / 2)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: when answering questions, try to take out the "personal" language.  Answers aren't chatty  like a forum,  they are more like a wikipedia entry :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use WPF. This should work in XAML:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinition>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding 1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding value}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Out of memory! You may have to adjust it a bit.

By the way: Variable names like "1" and "value" belong to the category of bad naming ;-) Hope it was just for the post and not for your real working code.

Next time you can also make clear in which technology you want it to display (WinForms, WPF, ASP.net, etc.).

Christoph